# Get a name of a user without mentioning them (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I was trying to @mention someone in the title of a embed, but it wasn't @mention -ing them. Instead it would show `<@user id>`.

```
if message.content.startswith('!meme'):
            link = message.content.replace('!meme ', '')
            memeEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Meme from {0.author.mention}".format(message), color=0x000000)
            memeEmbed.set_image(url=link)
            memeChannel = client.get_channel(772903403570987108)
            await memeChannel.send(embed=memeEmbed)
            await message.delete()
            userID = message.author.mention.replace('<@', '') .replace('>', '')
            user = client.get_user(int(userID))
            await user.send('Thank you for submitting a meme.')
```

The `{0.author.mention}".format(message)` should @mention the author. However, one of the features I want in my bot is that it can do that through servers. I realized that you can't @mention somebody in a server that the user isn't in. Is there a way to simply get the user's name without @mention -ing them? I have seen it happen in the node.js API bots. For example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxMku.png)

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post an image normally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the `author` is the person that sent the message, you already have their `User` instance. Because of that, you can just use `message.author.name` to get their name.

```
memeEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Meme from {0.author.name}".format(message), color=0x000000)
```

Also, I'd recommend using `Commands` instead of manually parsing everything in `on_message`. I see you doing this:

> if message.content.startswith('!meme')

which is unnecessary & will make your code a bit cluttered and hard to maintain if you end up creating more commands. It also doesn't allow a lot of things like for example aliases (without 90000 if-statements which, again, make your code less readable & maintainable).

Comment: Gonna have to try that :)
How do I do the commands?

Comment: This is an official basic example bot from the dpy github repo: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py

By the way, in case my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it yet because I'm caught up in a MLH event right now.